# How to install ZENOSS 4.2.5 on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, monitoring, zenoss

I want to install/setup `ZENOSS 4.2.5` on ubuntu 12.04.
But i have no idea how to achieve this.
Can anyone please tell me how can i do this?

Your reply will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Unofficial support for Ubuntu can be found in [Github](https://github.com/hydruid/zenoss/blob/master/core-autodeploy/4.2.5/zo425_ubuntu-debian.sh) (on Hydruid's blog. The link to Hydruid's Blog is dead! but here is the [link to the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20140701000137/http://hydruid-blog.com/?p=710) version from 25 June 2014.)

Source: http://wiki.zenoss.org/Install_Zenoss

Expect problems, because nobody maintains Ubuntu scripts for now. Recommended OS: CentOS, RHEL. Or Zenoss 5 has Ubuntu support.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.
I installed successfully but i am not able to access zenoss login page.
Can you please tell me what is the reason?

Comment: No, I can't. You didn't provide any logs and you want a reason? I'm not magician. Check logs, check documentation, use google, ....